# Extract DataSet from DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, dataset, type-conversion

I'm programming using WPF(c#). How can I save DataGrid content in a DataSet?

I used this code:

```
DataSet ds = (DataSet)dgBestCustomer.ItemsSource;
```

But it make error:
*Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataView' to type 'System.Data.DataSet'*.

Comment: Learn MVVM before you ever write a single line of code in WPF. Your data is already there. You own it. You don't need to request it from the UI. UI is Not Data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @HighCore has mentioned, in WPF, we work with data and `Binding`. We would normally set the `ItemsSource` property of the `DataGrid` to our data object like this:

dataGrid.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0];

Therefore, we would normally retrieve the values simply by looking in the `ds` variable.